# How can I avoid KeyUp event from being raised after filtering a window message into the overriden ProcessCmdKey method?

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard-events, keyup

I'm new to StackOverflow and I hope to write a question correctly.

I'm trying to implement keyboard shortcuts in my winform application.
Looking in the Microsoft MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms171535(v=vs.110).aspx) regarding the management of keyboard input, I learned that it's possible to intercept the pressure of shortcuts by pre-processing the corresponding message, sent to the window of the form, within the override of ProcessCmdKey method.
Since I have to process differently all the other keys, both individuals and their combinations, through the management of KeyDown and KeyUp events, I need that these events are not triggered when you press and release the last shortcut key.

Below there is the code that handles the keyboard input:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.Shift | Keys.End))
        {
            // now I need this to avoid making actions in the KeyUp event handler
            //if (filterNextKeyUp == false)
            //{
            //    filterNextKeyUp = true;
            //}
            return true;
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }

    private void ClientForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // do actions in reaction to key pressure
    }

    private void ClientForm_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // now I need this to avoid making actions in the KeyUp event handler..  
        // but I would not enter here if a shortcut was intercepted!!
        //if (filterNextKeyUp == true)
        //{
        //    filterNextKeyUp = false;
        //}
        //else
        //{
            // do actions in reaction to key release
        //}
    }
```

In this way it happens that the pressure message is filtered by ProcessCmdKey and then the KeyDown event is not triggered, but instead the KeyUp event is triggered when you release the last key shortcut.

How can I avoid that the KeyUp event is triggered, in a similar way to that in which I filter the KeyDown event?
Is there another method to override to achieve the purpose?

Comment: Using KeyUp when the user has to press 3 keys simultaneously is not a good idea.  The odds that he releases the keys in the expected order are just not very good.  The ProcessCmdKey() override is sufficient to detect the shortcut, no additional processing should be necessary.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer!
Yes, you're right, I must not suppose the order of the released keys and I have to store what released key to filter.
What I need is to know if there is a method into which i can catch the window message that triggers the KeyUp event, in the same way that I do in ProcessCmdKey() for preventing KeyDown events. :)

Comment: It is completely unclear to me why this is necessary.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: It is necessary because my application must handle the pressure and the release of each key, which I do in the event handlers KeyDown and KeyUp. The application must also intercept some user-defined shortcut to carry out operations completely different from those carried out in the event handlers.

Comment: That's why I do not want to be in the KeyDown or KeyUp if a shortcut happens.

Comment: That doesn't help much.  You have the hard requirement to make your shortcut keystroke key unambiguous so you don't care that you get the KeyUp notification.  If you *really* need up/down for "each key" then just return *false* from ProcessCmdKey() so you still get the KeyDown notification.

Comment: If I return false from ProcessCmdKey() I successfully filter the KeyDown event. Which method can I use for filtering the KeyUp event?
Thank you very much for your time and your attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the 'combination buttons' to do something when they are not combined with Ctrl, Shift or End?

If not, just handle those keys in the ProcessCmdKey as well:

```
public static bool HandleProcessCmdKey(this IPAMålepunktGui guiMålepunkt, Keys keyData)
        {
            switch (keyData)
            {
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.Right | Keys.Shift:
                case Keys.Enter:
                    // go to next field
                    return guiMålepunkt.NæsteFelt();
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Left | Keys.Shift:
                    // go to previous field
                    return guiMålepunkt.ForrigeFelt();
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Down | Keys.Shift:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Up | Keys.Shift:
                    // disable native navigation
                    return true;
                case Keys.Tab:
                case Keys.Tab | Keys.Control:
                    // go to next point
                    return guiMålepunkt.NæsteMålepunkt();
                case Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift:
                case Keys.Tab | Keys.Shift | Keys.Control:
                    // go to previous point
                    return guiMålepunkt.ForrigeMålepunkt();
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Or handle them directly in the KeyUp, by catching them later.

If you check them in the KeyUp, look at the KeyEventArgs there is property for Control and Shift (also Alt), that you can check. If KeyEventArg.Control then set it as Handled.

As for the End button - I think there is a Keyboard or something that you can call to ask is a specific key is pressed.